# How are proportions of clades and proportions of bipartitions calculated in `ape`?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, phylogeny, ape-phylo

Consider the following dataset:

```
fictional.df <- data.frame(L1 = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), 
                       L2 = c(0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0),
                       L3 = c(1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1), 
                       L4=c(0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0))
```

I converted this to a `phyDat` object and then created a pairwise distance matrix as follows:

```
fictional.phydat <- as.phyDat(fictional.df,
                          type="USER",levels=c("1","0"),
                          names=names(fictional.df))
fictional.hamming <- dist.hamming(fictional.phydat)
```

From this distance matrix, I then estimated a UPGMA tree:

```
fictional.upgma <- upgma(fictional.hamming)
```

I then created bootstrap datasets:

```
set.seed(187)
fictional.upgma.bs <- bootstrap.phyDat(fictional.phydat, FUN =  
function(xx) upgma(dist.hamming(xx)), bs=100)
```

I then calculated the proportion of partitions in the bootstrap set:

```
upgma.bs.part <- prop.part(fictional.upgma.bs)
```

So far so good. Here is where I would appreciate some help. When I call the function `prop.clades`, I do not understand the result:

```
prop.clades(fictional.upgma,fictional.upgma.bs)
[1] 100  NA  71
```

Why does this function return `NA` when there is evidence for that clade in the set of bootstrap trees?

A second question:

```
prop.clades(fictional.upgma,part=upgma.bs.part)
[1] 100  49 112
```

If there are only 100 bootstrap samples, why is the value for the final clade `112`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tree `fictional.upgma` is rooted and `prop.clades` return as default how often each bipartition occurs. In a rooted tree the two edges leading to the root both refer to the same bipartition or split:

```
prop.clades(unroot(fictional.upgma), fictional.upgma.bs)
[1] 100  71
```

For rooted trees you some times want to count the number of identical clades:

```
prop.clades(fictional.upgma, fictional.upgma.bs, rooted=TRUE)
[1] 100  49  71
```

This seems a bug and you best report it to Emmanuel Pardis

```
prop.clades(fictional.upgma,part=upgma.bs.part)
[1] 100  49 112
```